# Form Submitted twice and loading twice in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

When I am submitting a form using autocomplete the form is submitted twice and the resulted page loading twice.

Here is HTML Code.

```
<form name="searchArtForm" method="post" action='action.do'>
    <input type="text"  placeholder='search' name="keywords" id="searchInput" class="">
    <button id="searchButton" name="button" type="submit"><img alt="Search" src="/search-ltr.png"></button>
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery Code.

```
jQuery("#searchInput").autocomplete(data).result(function(){
    $('#searcharticleform').unbind('searchArtForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Please read when you're adding tags to your question. Java is not javascript.

Comment: "submitting a form using autocomplete" what would that mean?

Comment: autocomplete input box.

Comment: what is your `unbind` supposed to do? Do you really have the `searchArtForm` event?

Comment: jQuery("#searchInput").autocomplete(data).result(function(){
  $(this).closest("searchArtForm").submit(); 
 });

Just change above code to this one.
But still getting same problem.

Comment: Im not sure, because you didnt post any HTML but what about `preventDefault()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery("#searchInput").autocomplete(data).result(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#searcharticleform').unbind('searchArtForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Ohk, check if your javascript file is getting included more than once in the DOM, by check the times this function is being called. Also, please give us a way to debug and help you

Comment: It is not at all included in DOM. 
Just now i saw in firebug and that nothing it is showing related to autocomplete JQuery.

Comment: before unbinding just alert anything and check how many times you are getting the same alert ...

Comment: alert coming only once but still page is loading twice.

Comment: Then you are probably submitting the form using obj.submit from multiple places

Comment: I checked everything but still the problem is there.
Can you provide me some alternate as per the above code.

Comment: remove .submit() from the above line and see if it still submits the page?

Comment: so probably the function you have mentioned above is not the culprit but is happening in your code somewhere else. Please check that or post the complete code

Comment: If any alternate by updating JQuery etc.
plz mention,

Comment: Please post your complete code at jsfiddle for us to help you or paste your complete code here